# Irreducibility of $8x^3 -6x +1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I want to use Gauss' Theorem for that. So I have to show that $f(x) = 8x^3 -6x +1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which is equivalent to it not having any roots in $\mathbb{Z}$.
Since any integral root would have to divide $1$, one only has to check $\pm 1$. But $f(\pm 1) \ne 0$. So $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and then, by Gauss, irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Gauss' Lemma is that a polynomial is irreducible over the rationals if it is irreducible over the integers. But irreducible means not factorising, rather than not having a root. $4x^2-4x+1$ is reducible, but has no integer roots.

Comment: Argue by using the fact that it must have at least one linear factor had it been reducible

Comment: Rational root theorem and what Neel said.

Comment: Interesting but not directly related. Because $cos(3\theta)=4cos^3(\theta)-3cos(\theta)$ this question can be used to prove $\cos$ of some angles are not rational.

Comment: @almagest: Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As almagest pointed out in comments, your argument would seemingly apply to the *reducible* polynomial $4x^2-4x+1$ as well.  For non-monic polynomials, you need to check for *rational* roots, whose denominators divide the lead coefficient.  So in your case, you would need to evaluate $f(x)$ for $x=\pm1$, $\pm1/2$, $\pm1/4$, and $\pm1/8$.

For a different approach, note that

$$f(x+1)=8(x+1)^3-6(x+1)+1=8x^3+24x^2+18x+3$$

This allows you to use Eisenstein's criterion (with the prime $p=3$) to show the polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you. I like the solution by way of Eisenstein.

Comment: @Miriam, thanks.  Bernard's answer has a lot to recommend it as well.  Actually I think it's better than mine, since you can see at a glance that the substitution is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Set $u=2x$ and rewrite the polynomial as $u^3-3u+1$. The original polynomial  is reducible over $\mathbf Q$ if and only if this polynomial is. Having degree $3$,  it is reducible if and only if it has a rational root. Now the *rational root theorem* says this root can be only $\pm 1$. Furthermore, this root must be positive, hence you only have to test $1$, which is not a root. Hence the original polynomial is irreducible.